# validation and accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

i have two models :

```
 class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :league
  has_many :photos, :dependent => :destroy

  attr_accessible :content, :lead,  :title, :title_slug,
   :created_at, :updated_at, 
   :league_id, :photos_attributes

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos

  validates :content, :league, :presence => true
  validates :lead , :length => {maximum: 1000}, :presence => true
  validates :title ,:length => {maximum: 200}, :presence => true

  validates_associated :photos
```

and

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article

  attr_accessible :photo 

  validates :photo, presence: true

  has_attached_file :photo , :styles => { :medium => '440x312#', :small => '209x105!'}
end
```

My ArticlesController is

```
...
  def new
    @article = Article.new
    @article.photos.build
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(params[:article])
    if @article.save
      redirect_to([:admin,@article])
    else
      render 'new'
    end

  end
...
```

form view is :

```
= form_for([:admin,@article] , :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f|
  - if @article.errors.any?
    = render 'errors'

  = f.fields_for :photos do |builder|
    = builder.label :photo
    = builder.file_field :photo

...
```

i have some question about it :

1) I dont want to save an article without empty photo but now when i dont choose a file my article saves.

2) When i have some errors on article's fields and render 'new' ,my photo field dissapear , what is the rails way to resolve it.

3) in the future i want to add another model: photo_type and assosciate it with photo. Each article will have two photo fields , each with own type (for example: small , big) . I wonder how to render that fields and what can i do to save article with two photos with different types.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer for 1**: Use `validates_associated :photos`. [Documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#validates_associated)

**Answer for 2**: I guess that is an file attachment field. For that, this is generally done by setting up a hidden `cache` field and by using some callbacks. [MountUploader](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave#making-uploads-work-across-form-redisplays) uses the same principle.

**Answer for 3**: Little skeptical, but I guess something will work along this way:
In your `Article` model, have two associations with `Photo` as:

```
has_one :small_photo, :class_name => "Photo"
has_one :big_photo,   :class_name => "Photo"
```

This will enable you to have two sub-form fields present for both types while opening up the form for `Article`.

Hope it helps. Do comment if last one can work for you in this way. It looks like the good deal to me :)

Comment: thank you for answers. i've add validates_associated :photos but i don't know why it doesnt work form me. Every time i don't choose photo file my article model saves.

Comment: This must have definitely worked. `validates_associated` takes the associated models' validation in consideration too. Try adding these validation in `Photo`: `validates :photo, presence: true`

Comment: i've updated my models. I think that mayby i am doing something wrong in new or create action :/

Comment: It seems okay to me. You don't need `@article.photos.build`, since you are doing that in form by `builder`. But, I guess, that is not going to change this.

Comment: without @article.photos.build file upload field doesn't appear